# Java based memcached client, optimization of putting data inside memcache

Tags: java, optimization, serialization, memcached

I have say list of 1000 beans which I need to share among different projects. I use memcache for this purpose. Currently, loop is run over complete list and each bean is stored in memcache with some unique memcache id. I was wondering, instead of putting each and every bean in memcache independently. Put all the beans in hashmap with the same key which is used for storing beans in memcache, and then put this hashmap in memcache.
Will this give me any significant improvement over putting each and every bean individually in memcached. Or will this cause me any trouble because of large size of the object.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't get you any particular benefit -- it'll actually probably be slower on the load -- serialization is serialization, and adding a hashmap wrapper around it just increases the amount of data that needs to be deserialized and populated.  for retrievals, assuming that most lookups are desecrate by the key you want to use for your hashmap you'll have a much much slower retrieval time because you'll be pulling down the whole graph just to get to one of it's discreet member info.

Of course if the data is entirely static and you're only using memcached to populate values in various JVM's you can do it that way and just hold onto the hashmap in a static... but then you're multiplying your memory consumption by the number of nodes in the cluster...

Answer (score 0):

I did some [optimization work](http://dustin.github.com/2009/09/23/spymemcached-optimizations.html) in spymemcached that helps it do the right thing when doing the wire encoding.

This may, or may not help you with your application.  In general, just measure when you have performance questions about your app.